# C#/WINUI3: Data binding becomes invalid after using the OrderBy() to an ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, bind, winui-3

Part of the .xaml:

```
...
<ListView x:Name="DeviceList" ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.FliteredDevicesCollection,Mode=TwoWay}">
                            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate x:DataType="local1:BleDevice">
...
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        </ListView>
...
```

I created a custom class named `BleDivice`, and I bind the ItemsSource of the ListView to  `ObservableCollection<BleDevice> FliteredDevicesCollection`  to show the devices in the collection. The device list can be updated with the collection dynamically, which worked well.

Then I tried to reorder the devices in the collection I used `FliteredDevicesCollection = new ObservableCollection<BleDevice>(FliteredDevicesCollection.OrderBy(BleDevice => BleDevice.SignalStrength));` , however, the bind became invalid.

I printed the contents in the collection through Debug and found that it was indeed reordered, but the items in the listview no longer changed with the data in the collection. It seemed that the data binding had failed.

Is it caused by this method `OrderBy()`? I tried the indirect way, but it still didn't solve the problem.
So what is the reason and how to solve this problem, instead of using methods such as `DeviceList.ItemsSource = ViewModel.FliteredDevicesCollection;` in the .xaml.cs file after each reordering to rebind the data.

**New**

```
 private ObservableCollection<BleDevice> flierDevicesCollection { get; set; } = new();

    public ObservableCollection<BleDevice> FliteredDevicesCollection
    {
        get => flierDevicesCollection;
        set
        {
            flierDevicesCollection = value; 
            OnPropertyChanged("FliteredDevicesCollection");
        }
    }
```

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
```

I have already added the code above, but it doesn't work. It is strange that I can add objects to the collection or remove objects from the collection`FliteredDevicesCollection.Add(bleDevice);`, the ListView is updated normally, but I can't reorder the objects in the collection. These should all send notifications. Actually, the reorder progress has been done, but the binding between them failed, and the result couldn't be shown in the ListView. So what's the reason?

Comment: Do you have a dbContext?  There are linking between the context and the database and reordering will corrupt the links.  You should be able to do a query to the object and output to a new object.

Answer (score 0):

You don't show how you define your `FliteredDevicesCollection` property, but taking a wild guess I'd say it doesn't notify on property changes, which is correct. What you're doing is a lazy anti-pattern.

What you *should* be doing is to bind to a [`CollectionViewSource`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.data.collectionviewsource?view=winrt-22621), and set up filtering and/or ordering using the respective properties of that object. That is literally why that object exists in all XAML frameworks.

Comment: The reason is that no notification was sent, so the view did not receive it? However, I can add members to the collection or remove members. They work normally and the ListView is dynamically updated.

Comment: Are you confusing `INotifyPropertyChanged` with `INotifyCollectionChanged`?